# Agrupamento no LINQ com registros de múltiplas entidades

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho uma query LINQ que recupera a média de uma lista de Notas agrupadas por fontes de risco.

```
 var mediaControles = await (from ac in _context.AvaliacaoControle
 join c in _context.Controle on ac.ControleID equals c.ControleID
 join nc in _context.NotaControle on ac.NotaControleID equals 
 nc.NotaControleID
 group ac by ac.FonteDeRiscoID into groupDate
 select new EventoImpactoVM()
 {
 fonteID = groupDate.Key,
 NotaControle = groupDate.Average(p => p.NotaControle.Nota)
 }).ToListAsync();
```

A query abaixo recupera uma lista de fontes de risco agrupadas por Evento de Risco e com a média calculada do campo probabilidade (local do erro)
Calcula a média da média do campo Nota da tabela NotaControle da consulta anterior.

```
var avgProb = await (from ms in _context.AvaliacaoFonte
join prob in _context.Probabilidade on ms.ProbabilidadeID equals 
prob.ProbabilidadeID

//join da consulta anterior
join m_c in mediaControles on ms.FonteDeRiscoID equals m_c.fonteID
group new { m_c, ms } by ms into groupDate

select new EventoImpactoVM()
{                                         
eventoID = groupDate.Key.EventoID,
```

//cálculo da média das notas de probabilidade, não funciona! retorna um erro

> lambda_method(Closure , <>f__AnonymousType4 )

```
NotaProbabilidade = groupDate.Average(a 
=> a.ms.Probabilidade.NotaProbabilidade),

//cálculo da média da média
MediaControle = groupDate.Average(a => a.m_c.NotaControle)
}).ToListAsync();
```

Pelo que entendi o erro em questão aponta falha na instanciação da variável anônima ms, já tentei várias alternativas mas não consigo resolver, creio que o problema é no group new {m_c, ms}. Quando agrupo por apenas uma das variáveis m_c ou ms o erro não ocorre, quando faço o agrupamento pelas duas, somente m_c retorna o resultado.
Agradeço a todos que puderem ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Tente agrupar apenas pelos campos específicos (os campos que serão usados na sua cláusula **select**)  ao invés de tentar agrupar pela entidade inteira. Faça o seguinte:

```
group new 
{
    ms.EventoID, 
    ms.Probabilidade.NotaProbabilidade,
    m_c.NotaControle
} by ms into groupDate
```